# Unable to start adb server

Tags: android-studio, adb

Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
**error: unknown host service**
..\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Error in adb of Android Studio ,
my os is win7,
I did command `adb kill-server` ...> result:`error: unknown host service`, the command `adb start-server` ...> result : the same result , i moved file platform-tools with the new file Placed in response of friends in stackoverflow.com, Finally got a lot of work to solve this problem.
Please provide a detailed response,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Genymotion?

Recently I started to run into the same problem from time to time. Then I noticed that the problem happens only when I use Genymotion and not a default Android emulator.

It looks like Genymotion uses the same adb connection settings with its Genymotion Android tools that the Android Studio tries to use. As a result, we get conflicts and the problem you mentioned.

To resolve this issue, I suggest you try one of two ways:

1) Go to Genymotion -> Setting -> ADB, check "Use custom android SDK tools" and show path to your Android SDK destination.

[image: Genymotion adb settings]

2) Or you can try to use Android Emulator, which is now much faster comparing with his previos version (1.x), starting from version 2.0 and provides some features (like screenshots) that are not provided by free license of Genymotion. The drawback here is that default emulator take more RAM, but it will usually not be an issue if you have 16+ GB of RAM on your machine.

Comment: My problem was solved by changing the (adb.exe) file. ` **..\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe** ` . Gaket thank you for the advice you gave.

Answer (score 0):

ADB server is not created by the program you selected. it must be that another program created it so you can search for it in task manager and End task from there.
How to know it? most of the time it would has an ADB word in the name of the task in task manager ... Baidu PC Faster is one of the programs that usually creates an adb without giving any hint

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question unfortunately. It would have been better as a comment on the existing answer.